# Import project module into IEX session

Tags: elixir

I have an application called `MyApp` and whenever I open an IEx session via `iex -S mix` I have to call the repo like this: `MyApp.Repo.all(MyApp.User)`.

I would love it if I could automatically import the project module so that I only have to do this `Repo.all(User)` to get the same value as above.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [aliases with en .iex.exs file](https://niallburkley.com/blog/preloading-aliases-in-iex/). You create the file and add:

```
# .iex.exs
alias MyApp.Repo
```

And that will set these aliases for you. There are [other things you can do](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) with that file, like set variables up, or add some shell configuration.